# Draggable curve in JSXGraph

Tags: javascript, jsxgraph

I want to define a curve in JSXGraph that's draggable, similar to this example:

http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wiki/index.php/Draggable_exponential_function

However, instead of the function's shape changing based on a single point being dragged, I want to drag the entire curve itself, without it changing shape. In fact, the mathematical properties aren't so important for this case - it doesn't matter if I don't define it as a function, I just want to have a fixed curve on the graph that I can drag.

Can anyone give me an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A curve can be made draggable by setting the attribute `fixed:false`. Here is an example:

```
var board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('box1', {boundingbox: [-5, 20, 5, -2], axis:true});

var graph = board.create('functiongraph', [
     function(x) {
        return Math.sin(x) + 5;
     }], {fixed: false});
```

Best wishes,
Alfred

Comment: Thank you, this works.. almost. I can successfully drag and move the curve with `fixed: false`, but once I do that, it freezes in its place and I can't move it again. This may be a problem on my end, so I'll be investigating further.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this problem in the jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/3u9rk8nj/7/  See how you can drag the curve at first, then it freezes. I wonder if this is a jsxgraph bug - I'll continue to investigate.

Comment: Ah - actually, this issue is fixed when I use the latest git version of jsxgraph. Maybe the `moveTo()` method you added in `curve.js` resolved this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1st idea is to set `draggable:true` but this will not work.

2nd idea is to group points of the graph and then drag the group, however, the graph has not `vertices` that we could use. You can see it by `console.log(graph.points[0]);` which shows t.Coords instead of the needed Point object.

3rd idea is to set the position of the graph when dragging the visible point A, but it does not work: https://jsfiddle.net/3u9rk8nj/3/ Probably because the graph is updated during the drag.

4th idea is to **change the graph function on drag** to match the mouse coordinates. This works:

```
var board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('box1', {boundingbox: [-5, 20, 5, -2], axis:true});

var point_a = board.create('point', [0, 0] );
var graph = board.create('functiongraph', [
     function(x) {
        // adapt function outcome to match point dragging
        return Math.exp(x-point_a.X()) + point_a.Y();
     }]);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3u9rk8nj/4/

Comment: Thanks for these creative solutions. The 4th one works well. I'd really like to have the curve itself be draggable instead of an arbitrary point.. Currently I'm trying to get Alfred's suggestion of using fixed: false working.

Comment: Take Alfred's solution above (with the latest JSXgraph library). Much easier! :) - By the way, it didn't work for me either with the CDN version...